# Material-UI: The `css` function is deprecated. Use the `styleFunctionSx` instead

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have a component library `dot-components` which is based on `mui-org/material-ui`. I have another application which is using my `dot-components` component library and recently I have noticed a console warning appearing in my unit tests.

#### Console Warning

```
    console.warn
      Material-UI: The `css` function is deprecated. Use the `styleFunctionSx` instead.

      at css (../../node_modules/@material-ui/system/styleFunctionSx.js:75:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@material-ui/core/Box/Box.js:14:37)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@material-ui/core/Box/index.js:21:36)
```

The console warning in question is related to [mui-org/material-ui PR #23454](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/23454) however I have gone through my application as well as `dot-components` and have confirmed we are not using `Box` at all. I've looked through all of stack overflow and searched everywhere I could online. I even tried asking about it in [mui-org/material-ui #27799](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27799) however they are more concerned with closing issues than they are actually helping.

I am out of options here, and the only thing that I can think of is MUI is throwing a warning because it sees the use of `css` in my styled components

#### Styled Component Sample

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

export const StyledProductInstancesList = styled.div``;

export const StyledCard = styled(DotCard)`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    margin-bottom: ${theme.spacing(1)}px;
  `}
`;
```

I put together a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-villani-0lyxh?file=/src/App.spec.tsx) with a very clear minimal example of the issue I'm seeing.

#### Packages being imported

```
    @material-ui/core:  4.11.4 
    @material-ui/styles:  4.11.4 
    @material-ui/system:  4.12.1 
    @material-ui/types:  5.1.0 
    @material-ui/utils:  4.11.2 
    @types/react: 16.9.56 => 16.9.56 
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    styled-components: 5.2.1 => 5.2.1 
    typescript: ~4.0.3 => 4.0.7
```

Comment: Please show all the `@material-ui` package versions being used in `dot-components`. Without being able to see the `dot-components` code and packages used, it is difficult to make guesses about the cause of the warning.

Comment: I think the likely cause is that your version of `@material-ui/core` is older than your version of `@material-ui/system`.

Comment: As far as claiming that you aren't using `Box`, I suspect you are doing an import such as `import {Button} from "@material-ui/core"` instead of `import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"` and therefore executing the `index.js` in `@material-ui/core` which imports all of the components including `Box`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I've updated my question with what you requested. Also you're correct we are doing named imports, but if we are being specific about our imports such as `import {Button} from "@material-ui/core"` how would that be importing components that we aren't explicitly importing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple aspects to your problem:

#### 1. Why is the `Box` code and its [use of the css function](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui/src/Box/Box.js#L17) being executed?

In the comments you mention that you are doing named imports such as `import {Button} from "@material-ui/core"`. This can be safe and is discussed in detail here: https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#when-and-how-to-use-tree-shaking; but if you haven't taken steps mentioned in that guide, then doing a named import from `@material-ui/core` (especially in development mode such as when unit tests are executing) will execute the entire [index.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui/src/index.js#L39) in the root of that package which includes importing `Box`.

#### 2. Why is importing `Box` causing a console warning about the `css` function being deprecated?

This deprecation warning is coming from here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui-system/src/styleFunctionSx.js#L69. The reason you are getting the warning is because you are using a newer version (4.12.1) of `@material-ui/system` than the version (4.11.4) you are using for `@material-ui/core`. The [4.12.1 version of Box](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Box/Box.js#L17) no longer uses the `css` function and therefore would not get this warning.

Here is a very simple Code Sandbox reproducing the warning by leveraging the same versions as you: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-function-is-deprecated-hjzl2?file=/src/App.js.

Updating the `@material-ui/core` version to anything between 4.12.0 to 4.12.3 resolves the issue as shown in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-function-is-deprecated-forked-78qo7?file=/src/App.js

It is also possible to leave the `@material-ui/core` version at 4.11.4 and get rid of the warning by changing the import to `import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";` which then avoids executing any code in the root `index.js` ([sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-function-is-deprecated-ld7po?file=/src/App.js:0-46)), however I definitely recommend updating the version of `@material-ui/core` to 4.12.3 so it is fully in sync with the expectations of 4.12.1 of `@material-ui/system`.

Comment: Still working on resolving this issue. We went through all of the tree-shaking configs and the problem is still occurring. We also forced `@material-ui/system` to version `4.11.3` using `resolutions` in our `package.json`. I'm going to attempt to upgrade to `4.12.3` and see if that fixes our issue.

Comment: We just updated to `4.12.3` and the same error is occurring in regards to the `Material-UI: The `css` function is deprecated. Use the `styleFunctionSx` instead.` Any ideas?

Comment: I'm skeptical that you successfully updated to 4.12.3. Are you perhaps pulling in multiple copies of `@material-ui` via other dependencies?

Comment: Yeah I just recalled that I have a second package.json that I missed. Updated there and it looks like that did the trick. Any ideas on why the other config that we did with #1 didn't work?